# Better approach on Django signal managemanet

Tags: python, django, signals

Well, I have a django project which works fine.

In this project, I have following models:

```
class A:
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    c = models.ForeignKey(C)
    d = models.ForeignKey(D)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()

class B:
    # whatever

class C:
    # whatever

class D:
    # whatever

class E:
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)

# And more models...
```

So the general idea is that I have model A, which is the central of my structure. There are some other models which are either refer to or referred by model A.

The real issue is the 'last_update' field of model A. Ideally, the value of 'last_update' will be updated as current time-stamp when any of following happens:

1. user modify the value of fields of model A
2. user add, change, delete class B, C, D
3. user add, change, delete class E

General approach on this is to either override .save() of each model or hook the signals to pre_save of each model.

However, I want something much cleaner. Ideally, I only need one method which will receive different signals and react as the same way - update 'last_update' field of model A.

Thanks in advance.

PS: please do not mention solutions about database level modification (I mean something like trigger). Let's only focus on Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the core of your app, you might want to create a general signal receiver that listens to all model saves. If you still have a lot of models not directly connected to the `A` model, you might not want to do this.

```
import datetime

@receiver(post_save, sender=None, dispatch_uid='update_last_modified')
def update_last_modified(sender, instance, raw, using, update_fields):
    if raw: # database might not be in a consistent state yet
        return
    if sender in (B, C, D): # all models which A has a fk/m2m to
        qs = instance.a_set.using(using)
    elif sender in (E,): # all models which have a fk/o2o to A
        qs = A.objects.filter(pk=instance.a.pk).using(using)
    elif sender is A:
        qs = A.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk).using(using)
    try:
        qs.update(last_update=datetime.datetime.now())
    except NameError:
        pass
```

By constructing a queryset and using the `update` method, you prevent the signal from firing multiple times while saving a single instance.

I would hook into the `post_save` method instead of the `pre_save` method, so that m2m relations for newly created objects get saved before the signal is fired, and that the `last_update` field is not updated should an error occur in saving the model in the first case.

Comment: hook to post_save rather than pre_save does make a lot of sense. I still need to think about the approach. I think your one is promising. Let me do some experiments. If I do go your approach, you will have your green mark. Thanks dude.